# Webpack "DeprecationWarning: Tapable.apply is deprecated" for internal webpack ProgressPlugin

Tags: webpack

Webpack 4.0.1. `DeprecationWarning: Tapable.apply is deprecated. Call apply on the plugin directly instead` for Webpack internal `ProgressPlugin` (`webpack --progress`). Is it an issue of `ProgressPlugin` in Webpack or not?

Answer (score 0):

Since webpack 4 was to be launched, webpack team published all necessary changes every plugin/loader maintainer had to do in order to work with webpack 4. Not all of them applied those changes and that is what happens. Webpack just throws this error. That is a problem with ProgressPlugin, which should be updated.

Edit.

I found that this plugin seem to be an internal plugin, if so, that might have been deprecated.